# DBCC CHECKDB in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I'm trying to truncate a table in SQl Azure:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Product;
```

and getting error:

> Msg 608, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 No catalog entry found for
>   partition ID 0 in database 830. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC
>   CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.
>
> DBCC CHECKDB is unsupported in SQL Azure.

What can I do?

Drop and recreate the table?

Maybe, there are better ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd advise contacting Microsoft support for this one. Posting back your answer here will help others though!

Answer (score 0):

ok, small piece of information for you SQL Server and Windows Azure SQL Database are not the same...
WASD are TDS based upon SQL Server technology, hence the fact that somethings aren't possibel in WASD.

to see which things work or don't work in WASD check here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336253.aspx

another thing is that when you have any foreign keys available truncate will not be allowed and according to me that's the reason why it fails

check this MSDN Forum thread for more info : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ceeae474-fb19-4282-a56b-c0718f06e9ab/sql-azure-identity-reseed

Comment: Thank you, techmike2kx. But the question is not about supported or unsupported statements in SQL Azure.
First of all, how can I truncate the table if I get this error?
What can I do?

Comment: The thread is a bit old, and update is needed: (1) DBCC CHECKDB is supported in Azure SQL Server. still not supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse (which make sense). (2) TRUNCATE TABLE is supported in Azure SQL Server, and also in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.